# Devise with restful user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, devise

I have devise and users controller

## routes.rb

```
  devise_for :users
  
  resources :users do
    resources :blogs
  end
```

## users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def create
    @user = User.create(params[:user])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
    respond_with [@user, @asset]
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
    respond_with @user
  end
end
```

when I visit `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out`

I get

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show

Couldn't find User with id=sign_out
```

update:

```
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                                   users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                   users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                               users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                          users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                               users#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                          devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                      devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                     devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                            devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                           devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                              devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#destroy
```

Any solution?

Comment: What you're seeing is a routing error, though perhaps you know that. It looks like it's trying to respond with the Users#show action but without the stack trace, I can't be sure.  Try running `rake routes` and show us the portion dealing with users, that way we'll know if the `users/sign_out` route is getting mapped.

Comment: I dont understand how to set priority, I move `devise_for :users` below `resources :users`, but it didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because your session is destroyed by DELETE method.

From your `rake routes`:

```
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                        devise/sessions#destroy
```

And when you visit `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out`, you use GET

You can change method in `initializers/devise.rb`. Just set `config.sign_out_via` to `:get`

Comment: There is a brief description of this in the [devise issue tracker](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1192#issuecomment-1536551)

Answer (score 0):

Your routes.rb file and your generated routes don't appear to match. Routes are evaluated in order, and the first that matches is served.

You need your devise routes before your custom user routes.  Something like this...

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                           devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                          devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                      devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                     devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                          devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                            devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                           devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                              devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                                   devise/registrations#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                                   users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                                   users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                               users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                          users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#show
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                               users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                               users#destroy
```

I'd confirm that your routes file looks like what you posted, because it seems inconsistent.